# I want to understand various java debug options

Tags: java, debugging, remote-debugging

I am debugging a remote java process and can do it easily using eclipse. I want to understand the following command -

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=1045 -cp %p %m
```

I know that 1045 means the port, but other options are cryptic to me.

I am using Java 6. I read that for Java 5 and above instead one should use -

```
-agentlib:jdwp
```

What does that mean? Java docs are far from useful. I am relatively new to java, so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you're using is [Java Debug Wire Protocol](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/jdwp-spec.html) (shortened as jdwp), so the parameters after `-Xrunjdwp` tell how java virtual machine should provide remote access for debugging:

- `transport=dt_socket`: the transport method, in this case IP networking sockets
- `server=y`: remote connections should be accepted
- `suspend=y`: makes JVM to delay execution until debugger is attached
- `address=1045`: as you stated, the port number for remote connections

The command line parameter `-Xrunjdwp` used to provide access to jdwp as well, but that's getting deprecated (see `java -agentlib:jdwp=help`) and preferred method for invoking jdwp nowadays is, as already mentioned, `-agentlib:jdwp`.